# Return text at the end of a string - Presto SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I am trying to return the text at the end of my string.

```
Example #1- ad | aff | 11_32_32_Desired - Text
Example #2- ad | aff | 11_32_32_Desired Text
```

These are two variations that are inside my column, sometimes the length of the desired text will change throughout my data. I am trying to get the Desired Text values into their own columns. Some rows have the - and some don't.

Thanks!

Comment: Please show the results that you want.  And be clear on what the content of the column is.

Answer (score 0):

Presto SQL supports [regular expressions](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html), try:

```
SELECT regexp_extract(column, 'Example #(\d+)\- ad \| aff \| \d\d_\d\d_\d\d_(.*)', 2)
FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is the part of the string after the last occurrence of `_` then:

```
select substr(col, length(col) - strpos(reverse(col), '_') + 2)
```